# Azure kudu Int environment is displaying 503 error,service unavailable

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-virtual-network

When I am trying to access my kudu page, its displaying

> http error: 503 error service unavailable

I couldn't able to deploy anything and even if I want to delete logs I can't access kudu.

Comment: Could you ftp to your web app and delete logs?

Comment: Maybe you could restart your web app or try scale up web app service plan, then check again.

Comment: I did restart several times.Still facing the same issue.I connected through browser via ftp.I can see all the files in kudu but I don't see the option to delete those files.How to delete.what is the way to connect to delete those logs.

Comment: Could you use ftp client(such as FileZilla) to login your web app. Right click the file and you could use `delete`.

Comment: If you connect through browser via ftp, you could not see files. I suggest you could use some ftp tool. You could delete files in your web app.

Comment: I tried to connect through Filezilla only. error is: Connection timed out after 20 seconds of inactivity
Error: Could not connect to server 
Could not connect to server
Status: Waiting to retry...
Status: Resolving address of waws-prod-ch1-001.ftp.azurewebsites.windows.net
Status: Connecting to 168.62.232.23:23..

Comment: Even I gave port no as 23..Its not connecting

Comment: The port is wrong I think.

Comment: Host is like `ftp://waws-prod-dm1-037.ftp.azurewebsites.windows.net/site/wwwroot`

Comment: Yes,I am connecting without port also.But still saying same error.But I could able to access through browser but not able to delete.

Comment: Host is `ftp://waws-prod-ch1-001.ftp.azurewebsites.windows.net`? I test in my lab, the port 21 is listening.

Comment: Hi, does it work now?

Comment: No,In my company ,FTP port will not work,So We contacted microsoft team to help the help. Thanks for your support.

Comment: I suggest you could create a VM on Azure, then you could install ftp client and login web app.

Comment: If you scale up your web app to a larger size, same result?

Comment: @MSFT,That was resolved my Microsoft team. one software has been installed in that server that software is collapsed the Int environment.So microsoft team recognized and removed that software Now its up and running.Thank you so much for your quick response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I couldn't able to deploy anything and even if I want to delete logs I
>   can't access kudu.

You could use a Ftp client(such as Filezilla) to login your web app. Right click, you could see `Delete`, then you could delete logs.

If your company disable ftp port, I suggest you could create a VM in Azure, then you could bypass this limit.

According to your error log, I suggest you could restart your web app, if it still does not work, you could scale up your service plan to a lager size.